# How do I directly display an image using PHP?

Tags: php, image

I have a question about displaying images in PHP. I need to have a PHP file display as JUST an image, as opposed to an image embedded in a web page, as if you had browsed to the JPEG image directly. The reason that I need it to be a PHP page as opposed to actually browsing to the image is that I need to resize the image before it is delivered. It would be easiest to use an image directly because that way I can display the image in a desktop application more easily. Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: http://uk3.php.net/fpassthru

Comment: What are you using to do resizing?

Comment: if the resized image is going to be displayed more than a few times, it would be (a lot) more efficient to save the resized version to disc and output it directly as a regular image URL.

Answer (score 9):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile('path/to/image.jpeg');
```

Comment: `readfile()` is better if no processing is required on the file contents, because it just sends the file direct to the browser without loading it into PHP's memory, whereas `echo file_get_contents()` loads it into PHP's memory then outputs that, so it's doing twice as much as `readfile()`.

Comment: Surely if it was this easy, the web server itself could do it :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `header` `Content-Type` property to be the correct image type. See this link for the some examples.

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/image-headers-php/

Comment: Please include the relevant code, don't just link to answers. As per the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Choose the correct header :

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
```

And use php gd to change the image size : http://php.net/manual/fr/book.image.php